# Can't initialize webview2, EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null); fails

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace WebView2Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitWebView();
        }

        async void InitWebView()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
         //   var path = Path.Combine("file:", Application.StartupPath, "html", "index.html");
         //   webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(path);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have this demo app for testing webview2. It fails on line `webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async` with this error

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Comment: Uninstall / reinstall the NuGet package. Call `await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);` from the Form's `Load` event, making it `async`. -- Test a clean Project, installing the NuGet package from scratch -- What Windows System?

Comment: @R.Czq That's not necessary and not the cause of the problem, since it looks like the runtime is missing.

Comment: @Jimi I tried your suggestions. The system is Windows 10

Comment: @Jimi sorry about that, you are right. @Ashot if you try  `CoreWebView2Environment.GetAvailableBrowserVersionString();` what does it return?

Comment: So, what did you try? Did you build a new Solution, added the WebView2 NuGet Package 
(`1.0.1210.39`), initialized as described and got the same exception? It would be weird. -- Make sure not to use any of the newer pre-releases, since these are all bugged.

Comment: @R.Czq `101.0.1210.47`

Comment: @Ashot I would maybe try to get a previous version and see if that works, you have the latest one. Also make sure that you download the one for the right type of architecture, you probably already did this but I'm just saying wild guesses here.

Comment: Creating the same project from the scratch worked :)